# Webpack loads unwanted file when passing string+variable to require()

Tags: javascript, webpack

When running the following code I get an error when building with Webpack:

```js
const name = 'Test';
const test = require(`./app/model/${name}`);
```

However, with the following code I get no error:

```js
const test = require('./app/model/Test');
```

The error received is:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/path/to/maestro/node_modules/express/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 18:11-25
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./app/model/CommanderProgram.js
 @ ./app/model sync ^\.\/.*$
 @ ./web.js
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! xops-pat@4.0.0-rc1 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the xops-pat@4.0.0-rc1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /path/to/error/log/2019-12-09T16_19_45_494Z-debug.log
```

The contents of `./app/model/Test.js` are:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = 'asdf';
```

So no dependencies. The error above mentions `./app/model/CommanderProgram.js`, which absolutely should not be Webpack'd. Based on the fact that `Test.js` has nothing in it, Webpack should not be trying to include `CommanderProgram.js`, though. However, if I delete `CommanderProgram.js` then the error does NOT occur. Restoring `CommanderProgram.js` then renaming it to either `AAA.js` or `ZZZ.js` still DOES cause the problem (without updating references, so nothing could be importing `AAA.js`/`ZZZ.js`), so somehow Webpack is trying to include an un-referenced file.

I also tried the following, showing it's not an issue with template literals:

```js
const name = 'Test';
const test = require('./app/model/' + name);
```

Why does Webpack appear to include an un-referenced file when using variables in strings passed to `require`?

Environment:

- Node: v10.16.3
- OS: Windows 10
- Webpack: 4.41.2
- Webpack-cli: 3.3.10

See code here: https://github.com/xOPERATIONS/maestro/blob/9d7977f52c1a08bc947666f3b1c85c30787cb831/web.js

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem is documented here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression

In short, doing `require('./app/model/' + name)` makes Webpack include files in the directory `./app/model` matching regular expressing `.*` (i.e. everything in that directory). So while `CommanderProgram.js` was the module that caused errors, thus making this a problem, all other modules in that directory were also being included even if they were not desired.

EDIT: Replacing the string+variable with a function expression in this case will prevent the undesired file from being loaded, and thus the error will go away. However, using a function expression **will NOT solve the problem** of trying to load modules using variables.

**Original answer (does not work):**

To get around this, do one of the following (which all boil down to "wrap the string in a function"):

1. Construct an absolute path with `path.resolve()`:

```js
const test = require(path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/model', name));
```

2. Construct the require-string with a function:

```js
const myfunc = function(mod) {
    return `./app/model/${mod}`;
};

const name = 'Test';
const test = require(myfunc(name));
```

3. Construct the require-string with an IEFE (immediately envoking function expression):

```js
const test = require(
    (function() {
        return `./app/model/${name}`;
    }())
);
```